# Shortening if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I wrote a condition like:

```
if a>100 and b>100 and c>100 and d>100:

    print("yes")
```

I want to shorten it, is there any way to make it like this:

```
if (a,b,c,d)>100:

    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) along with a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/):

```
if all(value > 100 for value in [a, b, c, d]):
    print("yes")
```

Comment: Alternatively `if not any(value <= 100...`

Answer (score 3):

If the minimum of those values is greater than 100, then all of them are.

```
if min(a, b, c, d) > 100:
    print("yes")
```

This works well a for small number of values, but it may not be as fast as using `all` if you have a lot of values to test. `all` should return as soon as it finds one value that doesn't meet the condition, but `min` has to look at every one to find the minimum.